# nginx: how do I add new site/server_name in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm just starting to explore Nginx on my Ubuntu 10.04. I installed Nginx and I'm able to get the "Welcome to Nginx" page on localhost. However I'm not able to add a new server_name, even when I make the changes in site-available/default file. Tried reloading/restarting Nginx, but nothing works. One interesting observation. "http://mycomputername" in browser works. So somehow there is a command like 'server_name $hostname' somewhere over-riding my rule.

File: sites-available/mine.enpass

```
server {
   listen   80;
   server_name  mine.enpass ;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

   location / {
    root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    index  index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

File: nginx.confg

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;
tcp_nodelay        on;

gzip  on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml    application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to set up virutal host functionality?

Comment: I want access my host using http://my.mydomain. etc.

Comment: One interesting observation. `http://mycomputername` works. So somehow there is a command like 'server_name $hostname' somewhere over-riding my rule.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem but on OSX. Basically all of my server configs only work on localhost / mycomputername, no matter what the server_name is set to

Comment: A valid hostname cannot contain a period!

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation is to remove the default site by removing the symlink in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Then create your desired configuration in a new file, call it /etc/nginx/sites-available/your.host.name. Assuming you have your home page at /var/www/your.host.name, here's a very simple example:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name your.host.name;

        location / {
                root   /var/www/your.host.name;
                index  index.html;
        }
}
```

Then create a symlink in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your.host.name /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your.host.name
```

Finally, restart nginx:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Good luck.

Comment: root in location / is bad form.  It won't be available in any other locations.  Please read http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Comment: @kolbyjack - Thats ok, I will be doing proxy_pass anyway. But I just wanted to get the first step working.

Comment: @daveadams ( Doesn't work. I'll be adding my configuration files to original question.

Comment: @kolbyjack, thanks for pointing that out. I agree it's sloppy form. @Neo, is your mine.enpass config file symlinked in sites-enabled? If so, are you using "mine.enpass" in your web browser to access it? If yes to both, then I'm stumped without more info.

Comment: @daveadams - I followed your steps exactly. http://localhost 'still' works. But http://mine.enpass doesn't :(. I can attach nginx.conf as well.

Comment: @daveadams - Isn't there a need for the rewrite rule after server_name rule?

Comment: @Neo, you only need a rewrite rule if you're doing rewriting; it's not required. Can you run `tail -f -n 0 /var/log/nginx/error.log` in one window while restarting nginx (`sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`) in another, and post any resulting lines?

Comment: @daveadams - Nope, no output. Restart is clean. Looks like I'm missing something very silly.

Comment: @daveadams - One interesting observation. `http://mycomputername` works. So somehow there is a command like 'server_name $hostname' somewhere over-riding my rule.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `server_name  mine.enpass ;` to `server_name  mine.enpass;` in your sites-available/mine.enpass file

Comment: no luck. I'm able to make even proxy_pass work. But can't change the server_name!!

Comment: I honestly don't know where could be the problem,  `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` is the last line in the http {}, so there shouldn't be a chance for any other files/configs to override your server_name...

Comment: addam: Im pretty sure nginx does not read and apply configuration from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have not added `mine.enpass` to your `/etc/hosts` file?

This was the basic mistake I made, having the same issues with nginx but in OSX (stumbled upon the solution [here](https://github.com/pculture/unisubs/wiki/Nginx-on-osx))

Comment: mine.enpass is NOT a valid hostname!